# Epiceditor preview not working in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, epiceditor

I've been playing with this for a couple days now to no avail.  I've googled just about every descriptive phrase I can think of and nothing useful has turned up.

I have installed Epiceditor in Codeigniter and I have gotten it to the point that the preview button and full screen buttons 'work' and the css is properly working.  The issue is that the preview text(in both the preview button and the full screen side-by-side) does not show the proper formatting (bold, italic, etc.).  There are no console errors and I'm out of ideas at this point.

Code:

```
require(['epiceditor'], function() {
    var opts = {
        textarea: 'page_text',
        basePath: '/css/epiceditor',
        autogrow: true
    }
    var editor = new EpicEditor(opts).load();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you when using EpicEditor with requirejs. It seems that the epiceditor script includes [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) at the bottom and it is this that is being injected when require the script. Try this:

```
require(['epiceditor'], function(marked) {
    var opts = {
        textarea: 'page_text',
        basePath: '/css/epiceditor',
        autogrow: true,
        parser: marked
    }
    var editor = new EpicEditor(opts).load();
});
```